# Angular 4, ngrx\store Plunker - TypeError: store_1.StoreModule.provideStore is not a function

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

I'm trying to create an Angular 4 plunker which includes ngrx\store latest version:
https://embed.plnkr.co/cr4rCJ0hRVMwuLzKe4mg/

In order to use ngrx\store i've added this line in `config.js` file:

```
'@ngrx/store': 'https://npmcdn.com/@ngrx/store@4.0.0',
```

For some reason i'm getting this error:

```
(SystemJS) TypeError: store_1.StoreModule.provideStore is not a function
```

Can someone assist?

Comment: In `4.0` they have completely changed the store configuration. Read from [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45220561/providing-root-reducer-in-ngrx-store-4-0?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: @Aravind but I still need the ngrx/store lib, right ? Can you provide a plunker ?

Comment: The version update changed their packages. For instance payload property is no more in action model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the latest version of Ngrx the `provideStore` changed to `forRoot`.

Also you could have a look at the migration guide here https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/MIGRATION.md

Answer (score 0):

You should change 'provideStore' to 'forRoot' in latest version of Angular like Angular 6. It worked for me.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { UsersServiceService } from './users/users-service.service';
import { PDFGenerationService } from './pdf-generation-demo/pdf-generation.service';
import { AppRoutingModule, routingComponents } from './app-routing.module';
// Import ng-circle-progress
import { NgCircleProgressModule } from 'ng-circle-progress';
import { mainStoreReducer } from './state/reducers/reducer';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    routingComponents
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgCircleProgressModule.forRoot({
      // set defaults here
      radius: 100,
      outerStrokeWidth: 16,
      innerStrokeWidth: 8,
      outerStrokeColor: "#78C000",
      innerStrokeColor: "#C7E596",
      animationDuration: 300
    }),
    StoreModule.forRoot({ mainStoreReducer })
  ],
  exports: [   ],
  providers: [UsersServiceService, PDFGenerationService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```